# Vertical alignment of table cells and defining column width

Tags: tables, multicol

I'm currently experimenting with building an Excel app that writes latex code for a table from a selection area within Excel. Essentially the user selects their table in Excel, clicks a button, and the latex code for the table is written into a local text file and to the clipboard.

I've made good headway dealing with all horizontal and vertical borders, horizontal alignment and indenting, however I'm having trouble to vertical alignment and fixing column widths. I've used the array package and 'm' in defining the table environment, however it seems it's incompatible with the `\multicolumn` function I've used in the code.

I've attached a screenshot of the excel table, the automatically produced latex table, and the code below. Naturally since the whole process is automated, the latex is likely to be more complex that is can be (individual cell horizontal borders instead, since the process has to be completely dynamic. Also the table is pretty silly since I've tried to randomise merging and borders to test the ability of the code...

any suggestions would be great.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\MyIndent}{\hspace*{0.5cm}}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{m{5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1m} m{1cm} m{1cm} }

\multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5}\\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l||}{ 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4}\\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l||}{\MyIndent 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c||}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7}\\ 
 \cline{1-1} \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l||}{\MyIndent\MyIndent 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{8}\\  \cline{1-1} \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-6}
\end{tabular}
\caption{My caption}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you specify what the question is?